# Creating a camera class with LWJGL

Tags: java, camera, lwjgl

So i've recently started programming with LWJGL, and I have almost 2 years of Java experience. 
I'm having a hard time trying to get the camera to move properly (the camera is in a first person view). I want to be able to move around with the arrow keys and rotate the camera based on the mouse position. Does anybody know of a good tutorial for a camera class like this? I haven't been able to find anything close to what I need. Maybe some books as well that teach some 3D concepts?

Comment: I have one over [here](https://github.com/anubiann00b/VoxelDungeon/blob/master/src/game/Camera.java), I'll try to post that code as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one I made, should be fairly self explanatory

```
public class Camera {
    public static float moveSpeed = 0.5f;

    private static float maxLook = 85;

    private static float mouseSensitivity = 0.05f;

    private static Vector3f pos;
    private static Vector3f rotation;

    public static void create() {
        pos = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0);
        rotation = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0);
    }

    public static void apply() {
        if(rotation.y / 360 > 1) {
            rotation.y -= 360;
        } else if(rotation.y / 360 < -1) {
            rotation.y += 360;
        }
        glLoadIdentity();
        glRotatef(rotation.x, 1, 0, 0);
        glRotatef(rotation.y, 0, 1, 0);
        glRotatef(rotation.z, 0, 0, 1);
        glTranslatef(-pos.x, -pos.y, -pos.z);
    }

    public static void acceptInput(float delta) {
        acceptInputRotate(delta);
        acceptInputGrab();
        acceptInputMove(delta);
    }

    public static void acceptInputRotate(float delta) {
        if(Mouse.isGrabbed()) {
            float mouseDX = Mouse.getDX();
            float mouseDY = -Mouse.getDY();
            rotation.y += mouseDX * mouseSensitivity * delta;
            rotation.x += mouseDY * mouseSensitivity * delta;
            rotation.x = Math.max(-maxLook, Math.min(maxLook, rotation.x));
        }
    }

    public static void acceptInputGrab() {
        if(Mouse.isInsideWindow() && Mouse.isButtonDown(0)) {
            Mouse.setGrabbed(true);
        }
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE)) {
            Mouse.setGrabbed(false);
        }
    }

    public static void acceptInputMove(float delta) {
        boolean keyUp = Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W);
        boolean keyDown = Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S);
        boolean keyRight = Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D);
        boolean keyLeft = Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A);
        boolean keyFast = Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_Q);
        boolean keySlow = Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_E);
        boolean keyFlyUp = Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_SPACE);
        boolean keyFlyDown = Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LSHIFT);


        float speed;

        if(keyFast) {
            speed = moveSpeed * 5;
        }
        else if(keySlow) {
            speed = moveSpeed / 2;
        }
        else {
            speed = moveSpeed;
        }

        speed *= delta;

        if(keyFlyUp) {
            pos.y += speed;
        }
        if(keyFlyDown) {
            pos.y -= speed;
        }

        if(keyDown) {
            pos.x -= Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotation.y)) * speed;
            pos.z += Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation.y)) * speed;
        }
        if(keyUp) {
            pos.x += Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotation.y)) * speed;
            pos.z -= Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation.y)) * speed;
        }
        if(keyLeft) {
            pos.x += Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotation.y - 90)) * speed;
            pos.z -= Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation.y - 90)) * speed;
        }
        if(keyRight) {
            pos.x += Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotation.y + 90)) * speed;
            pos.z -= Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation.y + 90)) * speed;
        }
    }

    public static void setSpeed(float speed) {
        moveSpeed = speed;
    }

    public static void setPos(Vector3f pos) {
        Camera.pos = pos;
    }

    public static Vector3f getPos() {
        return pos;
    }

    public static void setX(float x) {
        pos.x = x;
    }

    public static float getX() {
        return pos.x;
    }

    public static void addToX(float x) {
        pos.x += x;
    }

    public static void setY(float y) {
        pos.y = y;
    }

    public static float getY() {
        return pos.y;
    }

    public static void addToY(float y) {
        pos.y += y;
    }

    public static void setZ(float z) {
        pos.z = z;
    }

    public static float getZ() {
        return pos.z;
    }

    public static void addToZ(float z) {
        pos.z += z;
    }

    public static void setRotation(Vector3f rotation) {
        Camera.rotation = rotation;
    }

    public static Vector3f getRotation() {
        return rotation;
    }

    public static void setRotationX(float x) {
        rotation.x = x;
    }

    public static float getRotationX() {
        return rotation.x;
    }

    public static void addToRotationX(float x) {
        rotation.x += x;
    }

    public static void setRotationY(float y) {
        rotation.y = y;
    }

    public static float getRotationY() {
        return rotation.y;
    }

    public static void addToRotationY(float y) {
        rotation.y += y;
    }

    public static void setRotationZ(float z) {
        rotation.z = z;
    }

    public static float getRotationZ() {
        return rotation.z;
    }

    public static void addToRotationZ(float z) {
        rotation.z += z;
    }

    public static void setMaxLook(float maxLook) {
        Camera.maxLook = maxLook;
    }

    public static float getMaxLook() {
        return maxLook;
    }

    public static void setMouseSensitivity(float mouseSensitivity) {
        Camera.mouseSensitivity = mouseSensitivity;
    }

    public static float getMouseSensitivity() {
        return mouseSensitivity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote one of these recently! Here are some of the most important parts:

Movement:

```
public static void updatePosition(int delta) {
    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W)) {
        posX -= (float)(Math.sin(-rotZ*Math.PI/180)*speed);
        posY -= (float)(Math.cos(-rotZ*Math.PI/180)*speed);
    }
    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S)) {
        posX += (float)(Math.sin(-rotZ*Math.PI/180)*speed);
        posY += (float)(Math.cos(-rotZ*Math.PI/180)*speed);
    }
    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A)) {
        posX += (float)(Math.sin((-rotZ-90)*Math.PI/180)*speed);
        posY += (float)(Math.cos((-rotZ-90)*Math.PI/180)*speed);
    }
    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D)) {
        posX += (float)(Math.sin((-rotZ+90)*Math.PI/180)*speed);
        posY += (float)(Math.cos((-rotZ+90)*Math.PI/180)*speed);;
    }
    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_SPACE))
        posZ += speed;
    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LSHIFT))
        posZ -= speed;
}
```

Note that `posX`, `posY`, `posZ`, `rotX`, `rotY`, and `rotZ` are doubles.

Now for mouse movement:

```
public static void updateRotation(int delta) {
    if (Mouse.isGrabbed()) {
        float mouseDX = Mouse.getDX()*0.128f;
        float mouseDY = Mouse.getDY()*0.128f;

        if (rotZ+mouseDX>=360)
            rotZ += mouseDX-360;
        else if (rotZ+mouseDX<0)
            rotZ += mouseDX+360);
        else
            rotX += mouseDX);

        if (rotX-mouseDY>=-89&&rotX-mouseDY<=89)
            rotation.setX(rotX-mouseDY);
        else if (rotX-mouseDY<-89)
            rotation.setX(-89);
        else if (rotX-mouseDY>89)
            rotation.setX(89);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to do `Mouse.setGrabbed(true)` at the beginning of your program.